# Update multiple cells in a column if multiple cells are changed in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a task list in excel that will input the current day, date, and time into a column based on the user entering an "x" in another column to indicate the task is completed.

From finding some code online, I have written a macro in the sheet code so that when a cell is updated to contain a value in `column E`. The current day, date, and time are populated in `column B`. It also clears the date if the cell content is deleted. This all works fine and dandy.

Now I am having issues with if a user were to select a range in `column E` to delete multiple "x"s at a time. The macro errors out and says there is a `Type Mismatch` on the line:

```
If Target.Value = 0 Then
```

How can I edit my code to have it also consider if the user selects a region and deletes the "x"s from it?

How can I make it so that just the input of "x" triggers the code to place the date info? Rather than any sort of content change.

**Please note:** The offset is set to 3 columns to the right for now because I don't want it to update the `B column` just yet. When this code is working properly I will switch the offset to -3.

```
    Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim DayName As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long

    'Sets the current time as TimeNow
    TimeNow = Now()
    'Gets the first 3 characters of the weekday and set it as DayName
    DayName = Left(Format(Date, "dddd"), 3)
    'Gets the last row # of the "TASK" column that isn't blank. (Continuously updates as new tasks are added)
    lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then

            If Target.Value = 0 Then
                ' The offset is set to 3 columns to the right for now because I don't want it to update the B column just yet. When this code is working properly I will switch the offset to -3.
                Target.Offset(, 3) = vbNullString
            Else
                Target.Offset(, 3) = DayName & " " & TimeNow

            End If

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to loop the values in the target range and compare each one at a time.

Comment: @ScottCraner could you give me a brief example of what it would look like? So that I may work off of your example

Comment: `For each rng in Target`  Do your code `Next rng`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run away from the problem with a bandaid solution. Deal with each changed cell in Target whether there is one cell or a thousand and one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E"), UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bye_bye
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("E:E"), UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
            'The offset is set to 3 columns to the right for now
            ' because I don't want it to update the B column just yet.
            'When this code is working properly I will switch the offset to -3.
            Select Case LCase(t.Value)
                Case vbNullString
                    t.Offset(, 3) = vbNullString
                Case "x"
                    t.Offset(, 3) = Format(Now, "ddd hh:mm:ss")
                Case Else
                    'do nothing?
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

bye_bye:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Remember to disable event handling before changing any cell's value on the worksheet or the worksheet_change will run on top of itself.

Comment: That was just an implementation so it wouldn't break for now. Definitely not a permanent fix. I see how my comment made it look like I was taking that as the solution.

I tried pasting in your code but it's not working. I don't fully understand what everything is doing in your code so I'm not sure what could be the issue. I have it entered on the Sheet1 code. Is yours meant to be placed in a module perhaps? 

Can you clarify what "LCase" means? How would the "On error" work in this situation? Finally, why is "Exit Sub" in the 3rd line of code?

Comment: EDIT: I removed the "exit sub" line and it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution would be to catch a mutiple selection and exit event before any of your code. I would recommend staying with the change event.

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
if Target.Cells.Count > 1 then exit sub
```

Comment: Great idea! I've included this so it at least won't break. Thank you